# If else in xargs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I want to compare the output of tail -1 to see if it's an empty string. For instance, if I am searching for a file with find, and I want to compare the result to "" (empty string), how do I do that? I have:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" | tail -1 | xargs -L1 bash -c 'if [$1 == ""] then echo "Empty"; else 
< echo $1; fi'
```

Basically, it will print out the file name if it's not empty, and will print "Empty" if there are no pdf files found by 'find'.

I've tried a number of different variations with using the if-else statements inside a single command, and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pipe output to `tail`, `xargs`, and so on...

Simply say:

```
(( $(find . -name "*.pdf" | wc -l) == 0)) && echo "Empty"
```

Comment: @user680936 It calculates the number of lines in the output.

Comment: One more question, where would I have the else statement? As in, if it's not empty, I just print out the file name

Comment: Use `||`.  For example, say: `(( $(find . -name "*.pdf" | wc -l) == 0)) && echo "Empty" || $(find . -name "*.pdf" | tail -1)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" | xargs -L1 bash -c 'if [ -s $0 ] ; then echo "$0"; else echo "File empty"; fi'
```

According to `man test` -s will check to see if the file size is zero.

Comment: For some reason, this didn't output anything for me. I think it might be because it's not doing the comparison in the if clause. what does -s refer to? and does $0 match to the file name?

Comment: Ah, sorry, -s checks the file size...you already mentioned that.

Comment: Just realized that I thought you wanted to print "Empty" for each pdf file with empty contents, not print empty if there are no pdf files.

Answer (score 2):

With `xargs` you can use the option `--no-run-if-empty`.

> --no-run-if-empty
>
> -r
>
> If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command. Normally, the command is run once even if there is no
>   input. This option is a GNU extension.

My use case exemple:

```
find /iDontExist | xargs du -sc
# produce the command `du -sc` on the current directory
# that wasn't the initial aim
```

A way to avoid this:

```
find /iDontExist | xargs --no-run-if-empty du -sc
```

hth

Comment: Not sure if this actually solves OPs problem but it really solved mine very very simply. Thank you <3!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function instead.

```
function tailx {
    if read -r LINE; then
        (
            echo "$LINE"
            while read -r LINE; do
                echo "$LINE"
            done
        ) | command tail "$@"
    else
        echo "Empty."
    fi
}
```

You can place that in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`. Run `exec bash -l` to reload your bash and run `find . -name "*.pdf" | tailx -1`. You can also customize that to become a shell script placed `/usr/local/bin` as `/usr/local/bin/tailx` instead. Just add `tailx "$@"` at the end of the script, and add the shell header at the beginning.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
tailx "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(find . -name *.pdf)
if [ -z $output ]; then
    echo "Empty"
fi
```

Comment: How would I enter that in the context of xargs? Is it inside bash -c?